# Stack of linked list of nodes

Tags: java, stack

Just finished spring break, having a hard time remembering some of this stuff.

Right now i am trying to create a Lstack class that will create a stack ADT implemented as a linked list of Nodes.

This is the Lstack class

```
public class Lstack {
    int numUsed = 0;
    Lstack list = new Lstack();
    public Lstack(){
    }
    public void push(Car x){

    }
}
```

How do i go about pushing Car x (an object) into the stack?

Answer (score 5):

A stack is a `LIFO` structure.
So if you implement it backed by a `linked list` then you should make sure that you `push` into **the same side** of the `list` that you `pop`.
Since this is a homework I will not provide more info. This should be adequate

Comment: I understand that, my question was how do i do this using objects. If i was just inputting strings or ints i would know how to do it.

Comment: `Lstack` I assume is your custom implementation of a list? This would store reference to a `Car` and to the next node of the `list`

Answer (score 0):

A stack is a Last-In / First-Out (LIFO) structure. So I would go this way:

The `Car` class must have a `next` member of the same class:

```
class Car {
    String brand;
    Car next;
    public Car(String brand, Car car) {
        this.brand = brand;
        next = car;
    }
    // And the class code goes on
}
```

As for the linked list:

```
 class Llist {
     Car top;
     public Llist() {
         top = null;
     }
     public void push(String carBrand) {
         top = new Car(carBrand, top);
     }
 }
```

Just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Did i do this right?

```
public class Lstack {
    int size;
    int numUsed = 0;
    Car[] list;
    public Lstack(){
        list = new Car[size];
    }
    public void push(Car x){
        list[numUsed] = x;
        numUsed++;
    }
    public Car pop(){
        Car temp;
        numUsed--;
        temp = list[numUsed];
        return temp;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(numUsed==0){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public int size(){
        return numUsed;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("TOP | ");
        for(int i = 0; i < numUsed; i++){
            System.out.print(list[i].plate +" | ");
        }
    }

}
```